# Rails - validate inclusion fails on rake test:integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rake, integration

I see different results when running 'rake test' and when running 'rake test:integration'.

When running all tests with 'rake test' all tests pass.
When running 'rake test:integration' I have a failed test because my model fails to validate inclusion of an attribute before saving.

My model looks something like:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payment_type
  validates :payment_type, :inclusion => PaymentType.all
  ...
end
```

PaymentType is a lookup table, which I have a fixture for.

When debugging the save method in the Order model I see that it fails the inclusion validation (again, only when running just the integration tests),
but

```
PaymentType.all.include?(payment_type)
```

evaluates to 'true'.

Any ideas why it fails when running only integration tests?